# Uncaught Error "Class not found" in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, oop, composer-php

I am trying to call my model file from another folder. I have provided both of these file structure.

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Models\Providers' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pro/app/Scripts/Providers/1/Scrape.php:17

I am calling the model file from a script folder located :

```
app/Scripts/Providers/1/Scrape.php
```

In this class I have the below :

```
namespace App\Scripts\Providers\1;
use App\Models;
```

Model file is located :

```
app/Models/Providers.php
```

Within this file I have the below:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

I have not shared the full content that I have in both of these files. If you would like to see the full content of these files please let me know.

This is how the Scrape.php looks like

```
<?php
namespace App\Scripts\Providers\1;
use App\Models\Providers;

class Scrape {
    public function __construct() {
        $test = new \App\Models\Providers();
        die(print_r($test, true));
    }
}

$obj = new Scrape();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a namespace that starts with a number.

Namespaces follow the same [basic rules for variable names](https://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> A valid variable **name starts with a letter or underscore**, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores

(Emphasis mine).

Thus, your declaration

```php
namespace App\Scripts\Providers\1
```

is basically **invalid**.

From that point forward, all bets are off.

First, change your namespace to a valid identifier (and I would advise choosing something more reasonable and recognizable than *numbers*, you can have descriptive names and there is simply **no reason** not to):

```
namespace App\Scripts\Providers\GroupWhatever
```

Logically, you'll have to rename the folder where this file resides. It used to be

```
app/Scripts/Providers/1/Scrape.php
```

so rename that directory to

```
app/Scripts/Providers/GroupWhatever/Scrape.php
```

(In both cases, replace `GroupWhatever` with something that makes sense for your application and domain).

From that point forward, if the class `\App\Models\Providers` exists at `app/Models/Providers.php`, it should work.

#### Important:

Another problem that there could exist, is that is not very clear what `Scripts/Scrape.php` is or how is it called.

This should work **if you are executing `Scrape.php` from within Laravel, by calling a Laravel controller or console application.**

If you are calling this script directly (e.g. by executing `php app/Scripts/Providers/1/Scrape.php` (or the corrected `app/Scripts/Providers/GroupWhatever/Scrape.php`) this simply won't work, since the autoloading logic is not run at all.

If you are executing your script manually, **on top of the above changes** you need to include composer autoload script, which is located at `vendor/autoload.php`.

Basically, add this line close to the top of your `Scrape.php`:

```php
require_once dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

(I think I put the appropriate amount of go-up-one-dir path-segments, but you make sure it matches the correct path in your installation).

Once that is in place, the autoloader will be run, and classes will be found.

Comment: i guess he has an autoloads problem, he should dump the autoload

Comment: It's unlikely, @Thamer. They are referring to a class in the `App\Model` namespace, from another class in the `App\Scripts` namespace. If one class is being autoloaded, the other should be autoloaded as well. I believe the more likely problem looks like they are trying to execute `Scrape.php` directly, and thus not executing the autoloader at all.

Comment: @yivi I have made the change but still the same error

Comment: @yivi if you know much about the autoloading please let me know as I been seeing that everywhere I been looking at

Comment: @Jibin How are you calling  `Scrape.php`? How is it executed?

Comment: Like you said I am calling the script directly by executing php FILEPATH

Answer (score -2):

In your `Scrape.php`, change your namespace to:

```
<?php
namespace App\Scripts\Providers\p1;
```

From [PHP manual comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php#104196),

> namespace (even nested or sub-namespace) cannot be just a number, it
>   must start with a letter. For example, lets say you want to use
>   namespace for versioning of your packages or versioning of your API:
>
> namespace Mynamespace\1;  // Illegal
>
> Instead use this: namespace
>
> Mynamespace\v1; // OK